# Reading JSON file inside C# using JSON.net

Tags: c#, json

I've retrieved a pretty big JSON file from a Steam web api. It has multiple objects and tokens. I'm wondering what the best way to go about reading this file inside C#.

There's an example of the sort of data this program will have to decode here: http://pastebin.com/nNw7usZW

The only data i'm interested is the items "icon_url_large", "market_name" and "type" inside the object "rgDescriptions". So far i've tried using

```
WebClient c = new WebClient();
var json = c.DownloadString(url);
JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
```

Not really sure where to progress from here, or how to use the parser results.
In the end I'm wanting to put the list of "market_name" values into a dropdownbox.

Thanks

Comment: You're in the right track, you just need to do a bit off research on parsing JSON.  If you can post a small relevant chunk of the json, somebody well probably post some code for parsing what you want.

Comment: You progress by typing "JSON.NET tutorial" into google. Then you read the first 4 to 5 links and try to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `Newtonsoft.Json.dll`, In that you have to create a class and declare a properties in it so you can DeserializeObject and use only those property which you want.

like

```
public class MyClass
        {

            public int First { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }

        }

 var abc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(jsonData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a class matching your json representation and deserialize it using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject method, or keep your JObject. JObject are dynamic objects, therefore your into dynamic then explore the object tree easily.

Working with JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

```
class MyDataObject
{
   public string Data1{get;set;}
   [...]
}

string jsonText = ...;
var dataObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyDataObject>(jsonText);
var myData = dataObject.Data1;
```

Working with JObject

```
WebClient c = new WebClient();
var json = c.DownloadString(url);
dynamic o = JObject.Parse(json); 

var myData = o.Data1;
```

The JObject option is simplier, but you won't benefit from static typing using it. Enjoy! :)